# Error Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?

Tags: java, maven

I try to run a project but gets this error. The computer is a new mac m1, previously this project was on windows

```
RROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project common-core: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debu
```

Comment: Please answer the question that the error message is asking you. Since that answer is probably that the error message's guess is correct, install a JDK and set `JAVA_HOME` to its install dir

Comment: What is your IDE?

Comment: @MehdiRahimi IteliJ

Comment: @g00se
dev@MacBook-Air ~ % echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home

Comment: java -version
java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)

Comment: But ARE you running a JRE rather than a JDK?

Comment: how can I check it. I got a macbook and I don't know how to do it ?

Comment: `ls -l $JAVA_HOME/bin/javac`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your *Intellij* in main menu go to this path:

> File -> Project Structure -> Platform Settings -> SDKs

In order to add new *JDK* click on **+** button and add *JDK* from your directory or just download a new one.

After that set your project's JDK:

> File -> Project Structure -> Project Settings -> Project

In this path check the ***Project SDK*** and ***Project language level*** sections.

---

Two other important settings you should check for JDK for Maven that running in *Intellij*:

***First:***

> File -> Settings -> Project -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Importing

Here in this path check **JDK for importer** section.

***Second:***

> File -> Settings -> Project -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Runner

Here check **JRE** section.

Comment: 1. I have /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home
2. I have JRE : Use Project JDK (java version "1.8.0_181.....